# Primefaces: How to make multiple inplace fields be editable and saveable from buttons

Tags: jsf, primefaces

We've got a `panelGrid` with many `inplace` fields. We've got buttons to `Edit` and `Save` all fields, but they currently just call each fields `widgetVar` value with show or hide, this seems really inefficient to me, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Probably not for the edit case, but what's keeping you from just submitting the form on save?

Answer (score 0):

You could possible use an onblur event.

```
<p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{yourBean.doFunction()}"/>
```

Comment: Do you mean adding an onblur event to each of my inplace fields?

Comment: No, just within your panelGrid

Comment: It's not possible to add an ajax event blur to the panelGrid